MQTT very simple program with 2 clients not sending/receiving messages using MQTTnet
I need to understand how MQTT works so I have written a very simple program and also I have tested it with MQTTX and MQTT Explorer. I made two projects with the same code hoping to be able to send a message from client1 to client2.
Both client have subscribed to the same topic. Btw the mosquitto process is online
So at first I Connect each client with the same code
_ = Connect();

while (!mqttClient1.IsConnected) 
{
    Console.Beep();<----useless but just to get an idea of how long it takes
}

the Connect s/r is this:
public async Task<Task> Connect()//SparkPreferences.MqttSpSetupClass setup, Int64 startupTime)
{

    try
    {
        mqttClient1 = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();
        string deathTopic = @"HXgN1.0 / group_id / NDEATH / machine_id";
        // Create client options object
        MqttClientOptionsBuilder builder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                            .WithClientId("IoApp")/*("Dev.To")*/
                                            .WithTcpServer("127.0.0.1", 1883).WithProtocolVersion(MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V311)
                                            .WithWillTopic(deathTopic)
                                            .WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                                            .WithWillPayload("{\"timestamp\":" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "}")
                                            .WithWillRetain(true);

    

        ManagedMqttClientOptions options = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                            .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                            .WithClientOptions(builder.Build())
    .Build();

        // Set up handlers
        mqttClient1.ConnectedAsync += MqttClient_ConnectedAsync;
        mqttClient1.ConnectingFailedAsync += MqttClient_ConnectingFailedAsync;
        mqttClient1.DisconnectedAsync += MqttClient_DisconnectedAsync;
        mqttClient1.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += MqttClient_ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync;


        await mqttClient1.SubscribeAsync("HXgN1.0/group_id/NCMD/machine_id");
    
        // Connect to the broker
        await mqttClient1.StartAsync(options);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}

And then I try to send a message mainly (for I am unsure) by checking in MqttX or Mqtt Explorer having them subscribed to # (all topics).
My send s/r is very simple
public void send(string topic, string message, bool retain)
{
    if (mqttClient1 != null)
    {
        mqttClient1.EnqueueAsync(topic, "message", MQTTnet.Protocol.MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce, retain);
    }
}

so
send("TOPIC", "AAAAA", true);

but nothing happens also chaning the topic
I thought that the problem might have been that I hadn't sent the birth certificate so I did this:
public class Birthcertificate
{
    public Birthcertificate()
    {
        timestamp = Helper.GetEpochTimeMsec();
    }
    public Birthcertificate(SparkPlugMetricClass _metric)
    {
        timestamp = Helper.GetEpochTimeMsec();
        metrics.Add(_metric);
    }

    public long timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<SparkPlugMetricClass> metrics { get; set; } = new       List<SparkPlugMetricClass>();
}



public object sendBirthCertificate(object value = null)
{
    var bc = new Birthcertificate();
    if (value != null)
    {
        if (value.GetType().Name == "Int64")
        {
            bc.timestamp = (Int64)value;
        }
    }
    //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Types.MetricClassAppCmd> entry in cmds)
    //{
    //  bc.metrics.Add(entry.Value.getSpmMetric());
    //}
    //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Types.MetricClassAppProperty> entry in properties)
    //{
    //  bc.metrics.Add(entry.Value.GetSpmValueChangeFlag());
    //}
    string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bc);
    send("HXgN1.0/group_id/NBIRTH/machine_id", message, true);
    return true;
}

Thank you for any help!
Patrick

Not wishing to state the obvious, but have you tried adding an else block to the send() function to double check that the mqttClient1 isn't null?

Thank you I put a breakpoint on the send to make sure it was hit

you are subscribing to HXgN1.0/group_id/NCMD/machine_id but sending to TOPIC. I'm not sure how you expect that to work, but if you are just testing you probably want to use the same topic for sending and subscription.

Also, what broker are you using? MqttNet includes a broker, but you need to configure and start it, or use some third party broker.
